# IabHelper Android In-App billing 3 responseList is empty

Tags: android, in-app-purchases

Нужно получить цену  и друге подробности in-app. D IabHelper responseList  пустой и не заходит в цикл

```
  for (String thisResponse : responseList)
```

Пробовала разные комбинации `DETAILS_LIST`/`ITEM_ID_LIST`. Не помогло. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать правильно. Или ссылку на хороший туториал.

```
int querySkuDetails(String ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, Inventory inv, List<String> moreSkus) throws RemoteException, JSONException {

    logDebug("Querying SKU details.");
    ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
    skuList.addAll(inv.getAllOwnedSkus());
    if (moreSkus != null) skuList.addAll(moreSkus);

    if (skuList.size() == 0) {
        logDebug("queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.");
        return BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK;
    }
    Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
    //querySkus.putStringArrayList(GET_SKU_DETAILS_ITEM_LIST, skuList);
    querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST",skuList);
    Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, mContext.getPackageName(),
            ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, querySkus);
    ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails.getStringArrayList(
            RESPONSE_GET_SKU_DETAILS_LIST);
    Log.d("Sku skuList",skuList.toString());
    Log.d("Sku querySkus",querySkus.toString());
    Log.d("Sku skuDetails",skuDetails.toString());
    Log.d("Sku responseList"," +"+responseList.isEmpty());

    for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
        SkuDetails d = new SkuDetails(thisResponse);
        logDebug("Got sku details: " + d);
        inv.addSkuDetails(d);
    }
    return BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK;
}
```

Comment: napp billing не возвращает данные по позициям, которы вы не запрашиваете. Вы в moreSkus передаете ID товаров, инфу по которым хотите получить? И в google play у вас приложение опубликовано?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно сформировать список всех товаров которые у вас есть. Например в **OnCreate**():

```
additionalSkuList = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    additionalSkuList.add("shop_Item1");
    additionalSkuList.add("shop_Item2");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
billingInit();
```

Потом сделаем инициализацию:

```
private void billingInit() {
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                return;
            }

            // проверяем наши товары, сюда и добавляем наш список additionalSkuList
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true,additionalSkuList,mGotInventoryListener);

        }
    });
}
```

Убьете двух зайцев и проверите куплены ли товары и узнаете цену.

```
// Слушатель для востановителя покупок.
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            //узнаем цену всех товаров
            int price_item_1 = inventory.getSkuDetails("shop_Item1").getPrice();
            int price_item_2 = inventory.getSkuDetails("shop_Item2").getPrice();

            //Узнаем приобретены ли они
            Purchase purchase_1 = inventory.getPurchase("shop_Item1");
            if (purchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                //здесь делаем что-то если этот товар куплен.
            }
            Purchase purchase_2 = inventory.getPurchase("shop_Item2");
            if (purchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                //здесь делаем что-то если этот товар куплен.
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("TWD",e.getMessage());
        }

    }
};
```